# $\Bbb Z_{(p)}\otimes_{\Bbb Z} \Bbb Z/q^k$ is zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

For primes $p\neq q$, is it true that $\Bbb Z_{(p)}\otimes_{\Bbb Z} \Bbb Z/q^k$ is zero? If the answer is yes, how do I prove it?

Comment: Does $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ denote the $p$-adics, localization at $(p)$, or...?

Comment: Localization at prime $p$. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $a\otimes b = (n\cdot\frac{a}{n})\otimes b = n(\frac{a}{n}\otimes b) = \frac{a}{n}\otimes (nb)$, if $n\in\Bbb Z$ isn't divisible by $p$.

Comment: Oh so I just write $a\otimes b$ in the tensor product as $a/q^k\otimes q^kb=0$ ? @Stahl

Comment: @DontBeLikeMe that oughta do it.

Comment: Thank you @Stahl. What about $\Bbb Z_{(p)}\otimes_{\Bbb Z} \Bbb Z/p^k$? That's nonzero, right? Can we say something more?

Comment: @DontBeLikeMe It is nonzero: $\Bbb Z_{(p)}\times\Bbb Z/p^k$ admits a nonzero bilinear map to $\Bbb Z/p^k$ (because you can reduce an element of $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ mod $p^k$). As for "can we say something more?" it kind of depends on what "more" you want to say.

Comment: Is the induced map $\Bbb Z_{(p)}\otimes \Bbb Z/p^k\to \Bbb Z/p^k$ an isomorphism? Could you elaborate on how you obtain your bilinear map? @Stahl

Comment: @DontBeLikeMe $(a,b)\mapsto ab\pmod{p^k}$. In general, $A/I\otimes_A M\cong M/IM$ for an $A$-module $M$ and an ideal $I\subseteq A$. Thus, $\Bbb Z_{(p)}\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Z/(p^k)\cong\Bbb Z_{(p)}/p^k\Bbb Z_{(p)}$, which I'll let you compute.

Comment: Thanks again @Stahl. I am confused, isn't $p^k \Bbb Z_{(p)}= \Bbb Z_{(p)}$? Could you tell me the result?

Comment: @DontBeLikeMe $p^k\Bbb Z_{(p)} = \{\frac{a}{b}\in\Bbb Q\mid a\in p^k\Bbb Z, p\not\mid b\}$. That is, all numerators must be divisible by $p^k$, which is certainly not the case in general. If you want to prove your isomorphism $\Bbb Z_{(p)}/p^k\Bbb Z_{(p)}\cong\Bbb Z/(p^k)$, consider the map $\Bbb Z_{(p)}\to\Bbb Z/(p^k)$ given by $\frac{a}{b}\mapsto ab^{-1}\pmod{p^k}$. Check that this is well-defined, and note that since $\Bbb Z\subseteq\Bbb Z_{(p)}$, it is surjective. Compute the kernel, and then use the first isomorphism theorem for rings.

Comment: Sorry for the annoying follow up questions, but do you really mean $\frac{a}{b}\mapsto ab^{-1} mod p^k$? That doesn't even need to be an integer, or?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49622/discussion-between-stahl-and-dontbelikeme).

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbf Z_{(p)}\otimes_\mathbf Z \mathbf Z/q^k\simeq \mathbf Z_{(p)}/q^k\mathbf Z_{(p)} $. Now $\;q^k\mathbf Z_{(p)}=\mathbf Z_{(p)}$ since $q$, hence $q^k\notin(p)$.

Comment: Thanks. What would $p^k\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ be? Is that trivial?

Comment: Well, just the ideal generated by $p^k$ in the D.V.R. $\mathbf Z_{(p)}$, there's nothing more to say. The ideals of this ring are linearly ordered, and generated by some (unique) power of $p$.